# PHP защита от накрутки

Tags: php

У меня есть страничка, на ней рандомно выводится 2 новости, и пользователь выбирает ту, которая лучше. Всего 10 новостей.

После голоса данные отправляются POST запросом на страничку handle, где в БД заносится +1 для лучшей новости, дальше редирект опять же на 2, уже других новости.

Вопрос: как защитить рейтинг новости от накрутки. 
POST запрос для одной и той же новости можно повторить кучу раз...

Допишу: пользователь может голосовать **бесконечно раз**. Но новости появляются рандомно. 
Мне нужно защитить только повтор одного и того же POST запроса.

Замечание: **На сайте нужно обойтись без регистрации**

Comment: А реализовать в БД колонку IP адресов и сравнивать с ними?

Comment: пользователь может голосовать бесконечно раз, но каждый раз 2 рандомные новости

Comment: Можно хранить пару IP:ID-новости и если такая уже есть, то голос не считать.

Comment: пользователь имеет возможность голосовать несколько раз за новость, если она ему выпала

Comment: @Construct 3 часа назад уже предлагал. Я присоединяюсь. 

Передаете каждый раз случайный ключ. Запоминаете его. Принимаете только один ответ (независимо от IP) с этим ключем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реализуй регистрацию пользователей, там проще уже будет работать, записываешь в БД о голосовавшем

Comment: ИМХО, самый верный подход.

Comment: Просто в других вариациях, есть возможность накрутки, такой как смена IP, сессий, кук и прочего, а тут уже по новой регистрация(но думаю он уже дальше сам додумает)

Comment: К сожалению на сайте не будет регистрации.

Смысл в том, что накрутить можно только повторяя один и тот же запрос, POST запрос. Я думал, может нужно генерировать какой-то ключ... Может кто-то развить эту тему?

Comment: сделай к примеру шифрование времени допустим в md5 и сравниванием получишь, то что нужно. Я где то в книжке читал, один программист из гугла про это писал
когда отправка запроса идет, генерируется md5 -времени, затем оно сравнивается в хэндли,если запрос будет повторятся, то всё равно эти md5 не совпадут, ну а в прочем технологий шифрований достаточно, чтобы выбрать свою

Comment: Ты имеешь виду брать md5(H:i:s) и передавать постом, а в handle сравнивать это значение?

Comment: Да, как то так

Comment: Это интересная идея

Comment: Можно и не хэш брать, а просто количество секунд unix time. :) Тогда и коллизий не будет. :)

Comment: А что мешает просто отправлять запрос со сгенеренным ключом?

Comment: если брать time, то время может быть разным.... все зависит от скорости

Answer (score 2):

Извините, но очень заинтересовало:

**md5(date('H:i:s')) и передавать постом, а в handle сравнивать это значение.**

А с чем сравнивать? Время каждый раз будет ведь разное, следовательно и запрос каждый раз будет проходить. И что в целом даст шифрование времени? Как это поможет не повторить 2 3 4 5 и т.д запрос?

Comment: И я о том же.

Comment: Дык, я на js делаю время и отправляю, а на сервере сравниваю. и Все замечательно. Если на секунду дольше не прокатит.

Comment: у меня выходит что-то вроде: md5(моя строка+md5(date(js)))
и все замечательно +)

Comment: А все понятно теперь. Но только что мне стоит обновить страничку и заного проголосовать и пошлется опять md5(md5(моя строка)+date(js)) и опять сравнится с серверной такой же строчкой и добавит голос. Это насколько я понял может защитить от стороннего вмешательства т.к они не будут знать ключа md5(md5(моя строка)+date(js))

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `news_table`
WHERE NOT IN (
    SELECT news_id FROM `voted_table` WHERE sesID=$SESID   
)
LIMIT 0,2
```

таблица news_table содержит новости, в таблицу voted_table пихаем id новости, за которую данный пользователь уже проголосовал.

$SESID берем из cookie. $SESID создаем для каждого посетителя уникальный. Думаю самый простой способ. Опять таки, если куки удалить, то этот метод захромает. Думаю как-то пойти в этом направлении.

Comment: думаю, намного быстрее будет мутить что-то с POST ключом...
Опять же: пользователь может голосовать за новость хоть 1000 раз, если она ему выпала(рандомно)